# What do you think is the cleanest way to write this algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm

Me and my friends all had to solve the same problem. We discussed our solutions later and we couldn't agree who had the best solution.

```
 public static boolean doesContain1 (List<Integer> list, Integer value){
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            if(list.get(i).equals(value)){
                return true;
            }
        } 
        return false;
 }

 public static boolean doesContain2 (List<Integer> list, Integer value){
        boolean result = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            if(list.get(i).equals(value)){
                result = true;
            }
        } 
        return result;
 }

public static boolean doesContain3 (List<Integer> list, Integer value){
        boolean result = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            if(list.get(i).equals(value)){
                result = true;
                break;
            }
        } 
        return result;
 }
```

The first one contains two return statements, which is discouraged.
The second one iterates through the remainder of the list, even if it found a match, which is wasted time.
The third one contains a break statement, which is discouraged.

Which is the most performant solution?

Comment: What's wrong with `return list.contains(value)`?

Comment: The 1st option is the best one, at least the `contains(...)` method do something equivalent.

Comment: Nothing would be wrong with list.contains(value), I simplified the methods so everybody can read them in a glance. The focus of the question is the number of return methods, break usage, performance issues.

Comment: Your question has no sense, The faster you return the result the better it is, and don't make a method for something that already exists : list.contains(value)

Comment: Performance can be measured with practical approaches. Create large lists of integers and pass them to all three methods and measure the processing time.

Comment: 2 return statements won't create any performance issues. Looking even at that is actually microoptimization.

Comment: Did you consider the variant of implementation #2 where `i < list.size()` is replaced by `!result && i < list.size()`?

Comment: Also your code fails if you have nulls in the list.

Comment: While "clean code" discussions are mainly opinion based, a fact-based answer could be provided regarding performance. I think this question can be salvaged with minor edits.

Comment: Look up the Java source code for reference; for example, `LinkedList.contains`: `for(AnyType tmp : this) if(tmp.equals(x)) return true; return false;` and other lists have similar methods.

Answer (score 2):

The `List` interface supports the [`contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) method. I imagine the best guess to resolve this is to rely on how the creators of Java implemented it. The different implementations of `List` (`ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, etc) implement it *slightly* differently, but they all more or less do it as in `doesContain1`.

It is not discouraged to have 2 `return` statements. It is also not discouraged to use a `break` statement. The only thing that would be discouraged is the example in the middle, because it does waste computational resources after the result has already been found.